# Erasing values from a list in a nested for loop

Tags: c++, list

I'm trying to create a list of prime numbers using a linked list.

My plan was to use two iterators to basically do the Sieve of Eratosthenes. I start one iterator and make that the current prime, which will start at 2. It goes into another iteration removing every multiple of that number, leaving no multiples of 2 and a prime number for the next increment, which in this case would be 3. It exits the 2nd loop and starts over with this new list with an increment by one. Once it finishes, the list should be only filled with prime numbers.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int maxnum = 1001;
    int prime;
    list<int> mylist;
    list<int>::iterator it1, it2;

    for(int i=2; i<maxnum; ++i)
        mylist.push_back(i);

    it2 = mylist.begin();

    for(it2; it2!=mylist.end(); ++it2){
        prime = *it2;
        it1 = it2;
        for(it1; it1!=mylist.end(); ++it1){
            if(*it1%prime == 0)
                mylist.erase(it1);
        }

    }

    for (it1 = mylist.begin(); it1!=mylist.end(); ++it1)
        cout << " " << *it1;
}
```

I can't find any examples of a nested list being used like this, so I don't know if something is innately wrong with doing this with lists. I've been stuck on segmentation faults.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Ok, I figured out my problems. From now on I will always iterate with a while when using lists. Here is the working code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int maxnum = 1001;
    int prime;
    list<int> mylist;
    list<int>::iterator it1, it2;

    for(int i=2; i<maxnum; ++i)
        mylist.push_back(i);

    it2 = mylist.begin();

    while (it2!=mylist.end()){
        prime = *it2;
        it1 = it2;
        ++it1;
        while (it1!=mylist.end()){
            if(*it1%prime == 0)
                it1 = mylist.erase(it1);
            else
                ++it1;
        }
        ++it2;
    }
    it1 = mylist.begin();
    for (it1; it1!=mylist.end(); ++it1)
        cout << " " << *it1;
}
```

Comment: @awesomeyi I set it1=it2 in the first loop.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ mylist.erase(it1) is the correct syntax.

Comment: You have two issues. One is the erasing of the prime number, the other is invalidating the iterator due to erase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(it1; it1!=mylist.end(); ++it1){
        if(*it1%prime == 0)
            mylist.erase(it1);
```

replace it with

```
++it1; //otherwise you actually delete the number you are checking!!!   
while (it1!=mylist.end())
   if((*it1%prime))             // imho the better way of checking ;)
      ++it1;
   else
      it1 = mylist.erase(it1);  //erase returns the next iterator
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this code:

```
for(it1; it1!=mylist.end(); ++it1){
  if(*it1%prime == 0)
    mylist.erase(it1);
}
```

When you're calling `mylist.erase(it1)` it1 is no longer usable. The element where it points have been erased from the list and thus you cannot iterate any more on this `it1`.

You can use the return value of `erase` that gives the next valid iterator, but in that case you cannot use the for loop anymore as it would iterate even after deletion.

Here is an example of correct usage of `erase` (**it should be adapted to suit your algorithm**):

```
it1 = mylist.begin();
while (mylist.end() != it1)
{
   if(*it1%prime == 0) 
   {
     it1 = mylist.erase(it1);
   }
   else
   {
     ++it1;
   }
}
```

Another option would be to iterate before erasing. It would work for `list` as`erase` does not invalid the other list iterators.

```
it1 = mylist.begin();
while (mylist.end() != it1)
{
   iterator it3 = it1;
   ++it1;
   if(*it3%prime == 0) 
   {
     mylist.erase(it3);
   }
}
```

But this would work for a `vector`as `erase` would potentially invalidate all the following iterators.

[Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase)

Comment: as the other answer by Remy, this fails, you clear the entire list, and from a point of efficency, this is even worse, as there is no need in checking the elements BEFORE it2, it is enough to initialize it1 to it2 and increment it once... (assuming you wouldn't delete your entire list, as in your case there is nothing left before anyway...)

Comment: This was intended to be an example of correct deletion usage, not a correction of the algorithm itself. I will add a warning to avoid misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

`std::list<T>::erase()` returns an `iterator` to the next item following the item being erased:

```
it1 = it2;
while (it1!=mylist.end()){
    if(*it1%prime == 0)
        it1 = mylist.erase(it1);
    else
        ++it1;
}
```

Comment: as posted in my answer, this will fail, as you actually remove the number you are checking, clearing the entire list